# Laravel 5.4: Illegal mix of collations

Tags: laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-5, mariadb, collation

I have the next error when I'm calling a stored procedure:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' (SQL: call sp_getUsuarios())
```

I'm using MariaDB, and in my database configuration I have:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I have **eleven** others stored procedures that work fine. Only that does not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the collation type of each table, and make sure that they have the same collation.

After that check also the collation type of each table field that you have use in operation.

I had encountered the same error, and that tricks works on me.

You either need to add `COLLATE` to the `WHERE` clause,

or add it to the IN parameter definition,

or alter the field itself:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

as the default collation for stored procedure parameters is `utf8_general_ci` and you can't mix collations.

Unless you need to sort data in Unicode order, I would suggest altering all your tables to use `utf8_general_ci` collation.

Comment: But is not Laravel supposed to do that job? I have other stored procedures that do work well.

Comment: And posting the procedure with the error and some informations would help us understand and figure it out

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could not change the collation of the table but it was necessary to do it in the field with which I made the JOIN of two tables. That was the problem. It is already resolved. A hug.